# Selecting customers who failed the first time and were successful on the next attempts

Tags: mysql

I have a database with two tables: `users` and `payments`. There is a one to many relationship between users and payments: each user can have one or more payments and a payment belongs to a user. Also, each payment can be successful or failed.

I need to create a query that tells me how many users failed on the first attempt and then were successful at least once.

Example:
Considering the following users and payments

```
CREATE TABLE users
(`id` int, `name` varchar(6), `email` varchar(7), `password` varchar(10), `created_at` timestamp, `updated_at` timestamp);

INSERT INTO users
(`id`, `name`, `email`, `password`)
VALUES
(1, 'name 1', 'email 1', 'password 1'),
(2, 'name 2', 'email 2', 'password 2'),
(3, 'name 3', 'email 3', 'password 3'),
(4, 'name 4', 'email 4', 'password 4'),
(5, 'name 5', 'email 5', 'password 5');


CREATE TABLE payments
(`id` int, `date` varchar(10), `status` varchar(7), `user_id` int ,`created_at` timestamp, `updated_at` timestamp);

INSERT INTO payments
(`id`, `date`, `status`, `user_id`)
VALUES
(1, '2019-01-01', 'success', 1),
(2, '2019-01-01', 'failed', 2),
(3, '2019-01-01', 'failed', 3),
(4, '2019-01-01', 'success', 4),
(5, '2019-01-01', 'failed', 5),
(6, '2019-02-01', 'success', 1),
(7, '2019-02-01', 'success', 2),
(8, '2019-02-01', 'success', 3),
(9, '2019-02-01', 'success', 4),
(10, '2019-02-01', 'failed', 5),
(11, '2019-03-01', 'success', 1),
(12, '2019-03-01', 'failed', 2),
(13, '2019-03-01', 'success', 3),
(14, '2019-03-01', 'failed', 4),
(15, '2019-03-01', 'failed', 5),
(16, '2019-04-01', 'success', 1),
(17, '2019-04-01', 'failed', 2),
(18, '2019-04-01', 'failed', 3),
(19, '2019-04-01', 'failed', 4),
(20, '2019-04-01', 'failed', 5),
(21, '2019-05-01', 'success', 1),
(22, '2019-05-01', 'failed', 2),
(23, '2019-05-01', 'failed', 3),
(24, '2019-05-01', 'failed', 4),
(25, '2019-05-01', 'failed', 5),
(26, '2019-06-01', 'success', 1),
(27, '2019-06-01', 'success', 2),
(28, '2019-06-01', 'failed', 3),
(29, '2019-06-01', 'failed', 4),
(30, '2019-06-01', 'failed', 5);
```

We can see that users with id 2 and 3 failed on `2019-01-01` but then had at least one successful payment on the following dates. The query that I need should return users 2 and 3.

Is this possible to achieve with pure SQL? Or do I need other language to loop through all users and check their payments and return only the ones that I want? I can do it "easily" with php for example.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which MySQL version you are using?

Comment: Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.27, for Linux (x86_64)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired result using Window function, If you are using MySQL version 8.0 or above -

```
SELECT distinct user_id
FROM(SELECT user_id, status, LAG(status) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY `date`) prev_status
     FROM payments) TEMP
WHERE status = 'success'
AND prev_status = 'failed'
```

Here is the [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=77df5593a874d555d1921069653fe133)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.user_id 
           FROM payments x 
           JOIN payments y 
             ON y.user_id = x.user_id 
            AND y.id < x.id 
            AND y.status = 'failed' 
          WHERE x.status = 'success';
```